# Grouping multiple items on a page

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-grouping

I am trying to create a SSRS report that will have multiple items such as charts and tablix on that will group by Customer.

For example we have 3 different charts which use different data sets but we want to show a group of charts by customer like Customer A has X amount of incidents, X amount of Problems and X amount of Service Request (but we want them displayed in charts)

I tried a list grouping but it keeps amending the whole group of charts data sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to combine a few different features to get this functionality.

First of all, when you have multiple elements such as charts, you'll want to insert a rectangle first and then drag the charts into it. This keeps their layout consistent.

Next, you will need to insert a Table. Delete the header row and two of the columns so you're left with just a single cell and the "Details" group. Set this to be grouped by customer ID. Also set it to page break between instances of the group.

Finally, drag the entire rectangle into this table cell. Now the entire contents of the rectangle will repeat with a separate customer on each page. The table inherently filters all the objects inside it to that customer.

Comment: Hi Steven, Thanks for your help. It doesn't seem to be working very well as there around 80 blank pages on my report. Any ideas?

Comment: If you export to Excel you will get one sheet per page. That is a good way to see if your pagebreaks are working correctly. If they are, you probably just have too much white space below your content or the margins are too big. If you are getting blank sheets then the pagebreak isn't grouped right. Don't get confused with the "pages" in the report preview, those are not actually page breaks.

Comment: Hello,I've released that this does not work at all and it doesn't filter, it's creating the charts but for every customer and I'm unsure how to filter this per customer.